# How to plug in a custom authorization module to liferay to integrate with WSO2 Identity Server

Tags: liferay, authorization, liferay-6, xacml, wso2-identity-server

I have a requirement to plugin a custom authorization module to liferay. For example when rendering the portlets I want to decide which portlets should be visible to the current user. Basically I wan't to intercept before the portlet rendering and do a XACML based authorization with an external Identity Provider and then depending on the result render only the portlets, pages for which the user has permissions.

How to achieve this kind of a requirement? What is the extension point of Liferay to do this?

Comment: Out of curiosity, which XACML engine are you using? Wrt Liferay, look for the Authorization APIs and hooks Liferay provides you with (https://www.liferay.com/documentation/liferay-portal/6.0/development/-/ai/hooks)

Comment: Thanks. Will have a look into them. I am trying to plug into WSO2 Identity Servers XACML engine.

Comment: Have a look at the Axiomatics SDKs for Liferay support too.

Answer (score 2):

This is how we achieved the same requirement and you may use the same approach:

1. Develop a custom XACML PEP (we called it as "xacml connector") using the WSO2 IS SOAP service named as "EntitlementService" and calling the operation "getDecision". This PEP should convert the authorization request into XACML form before communicating to IS for calling the "getDecision" operation.
2. Develop a generic portlet (we called it "SecuredGenericPortlet") which uses the jar generated in Step 1.

   ```
   public class SecuredGenericPortlet extends GenericPortlet {
    public boolean hasPermission(String userName, String action, String resourceName)
   {
   // For single resource and action
   // Call XACML connector operations
   }
   public boolean hasPermission(String userName, String resourceName, Map<String, String> userParam)
   {
    // For single resource and passing multiple user parameters
    // Call XACML connector operations
   }      
   public ArrayList<DecisionDTO> checkPermissionList(String userName, String action, String[] resourceNames)
   {
   // For multiple decision profile passing multiple resources
   // Call XACML connector operations
    }
   public ArrayList<DecisionDTO> checkPermissionList(String userName, String[] resourceNames, Map<String, String> userParam)
    {
     // For multiple decision profile passing multiple resources and multiple user parameters        
     // Call XACML connector operations
     }
   ```
3. Now you can generate any new portlet by extending the SecuredGenericPortlet and calling required "hasPermission" inside "doView" method.

   ```
   public class SamplePortlet extends SecuredGenericPortlet {
   @Override
   protected void doView(RenderRequest req, RenderResponse resp) throws PortletException,
                                                                    IOException {
    if (hasPermission(userName, "VIEW", req.getContextPath())) {
       // do your code here
       }
       }
   ```
4. In order to achieve better performance you may use thrift protocol in step 1 for communicating with the WSO2 IS and may use multi-threaded thrift based connection handling.